# Merging of Ethernet copper ports into 1

Tags: voltage, switches, ethernet, phy, copper

I have configured the copper ports of Ethernet switch as shown below. (i.e merged all the ports and made it has a single port). My understanding is there will be a signal overlap during the Auto-neg process, and it will corrupt the signal, due to this switch may not be able connect to any link partner.

Is my understanding correct?

Have anyone seen this kind of configuration before. Will this configuration work?

[image]

Comment: What on Earth are you hoping to achieve by doing this? Whatever it is, it's not going to work.

Comment: Just for mechanical reasons. Could you please explain why it won't work ? What could go wrong in electronics terms?

Comment: No, your understanding is not correct. That is also not an Ethernet switch. That configuration will not work.

Comment: You're connecting three outputs together, so they'll be constantly fighting each other.

Comment: At at point in time, only one port will be working. Would that work?

Comment: It depends what do you mean by "working", and still it should not be done.

Comment: Working means, communication between, transfer of data between the ports and the connector

Comment: If the unused outputs could be put into a high impedance state it might but I still don't see what it achieves.

Comment: If there is no communication, but even a cable plugged in, or worse another device connected, it won't work. After all these Ethernet designs you have already made, what makes you think something like this could work or be called Ethernet?

Comment: Yes, but is there any specific electrical reason that it might not work?

Comment: @Newbie yes: the impedance of each end of the cable needs to be correct; merging cables gives a different impedance even if the actual port could support a high impedance state (which an Ethernet port won't)

Comment: Looks like a violation of the Ethernet specification.

Answer (score 0):

No, it completely won't work, because each port of the Ethernet switch is trying to send out different signals and they interfere with each other. One port tries to send a 1 at the same time another port tries to send a 0.

You said you needed this for mechanical reasons. Have you considered adding the wires anyway (for mechanical reasons) but *not* connecting them to the Ethernet wires? You *can* just have a random wire in your product, if that's what is needed to stop it from falling apart. It doesn't have to be connected to something useful at both ends. If you do use metal wires with no electrical purpose, it's usually (but not always) a good idea to connect them to ground.

Comment: If at any point in time, only one port will work, then would it be fine?

Comment: @Newbie why would you do that? probably still not